# Access config variables in buldpack bin/compile using bush

Tags: heroku

I am creating the heroku deploy button. In app.json there is next config variable:

```
"env": {
  "PUBLISH_APP_DIR": {
    "value" : "/src/WebApp"
},
```

and, as expected, it is available in "Config Variables" section on https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?template=

The question is how I can access it value in buldpack bin/compile script? Bash is used as environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I have checked environment variables using 'printenv', and there is no `PUBLISH_APP_DIR`. `$(PUBLISH_APP_DIR)` and `$PUBLISH_APP_DIR` are empty also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found in buildpack api [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api), that

> The application config vars are passed to the buildpack as an argument (versus set in the environment) so that the buildpack can optionally export none, all or parts of the app config vars available in ENV_DIR when the compile script is run.
>
> The name of the file is the config key and the contents of the file is the config value. The equivalent of config var S3_KEY=8N029N81 is a file with the name S3_KEY and contents 8N029N81.